# Install valgrind in MacOS X

Tags: c, macos, debugging, homebrew, valgrind

I am not sure if I can install `valgrind` debugger in my Macbook Pro. I searched online but most posts are related to Ubuntu. Can someone tell if this is possible? If so, can it be by brew for example?

Comment: I've had no major problems (beyond needing to add custom suppressions) with downloading and building Valgrind from the SVN repository using the XCode (`clang` and `clang++`) compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "brew install valgrind" to install valgrind.

Comment: Thank you for responding .. I got this error message:
`valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.`

Comment: Valgrind released a new version on the 24th of October I believe, that does support Sierra. Which I am assuming is what you have. Try it now?